# npm intsllation failure at aws code build for md bootstrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm-install, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to use mdb pro in my angular application.
So, things were working for me for the last 3 months.

Following is the line from the package.json with token replaced

> "ng-uikit-pro-standard":
>   "git+https://oauth2:mytoken@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git",

Following is the output I'm seeing now. I'm running this on aws codebuild.

> npm ERR! Error while executing:
>
> npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t
>   https://oauth2:mytoken@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! fatal: unable to access
>   'https://oauth2:mytoken@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git/':
>   server certificate verification failed. CAfile:
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-02T14_05_27_185Z-debug.log
>
> [Container] 2018/12/02 14:05:27 Command did not exit successfully npm
>   install exit status 1
>
> [Container] 2018/12/02 14:05:27 Phase complete: INSTALL Success:
>   false
>
> [Container] 2018/12/02 14:05:27 Phase context status code:
>   COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm
>   install. Reason: exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the token generated had the expiry time.

I generated a new token and followed the instruction here to make it work.

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/

hopefully, it will help someone.